# Why wont this work in my rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this if condition that checks if the country is not in the USA

```
 if params[:address][:country] != 'United States'
  logger.info "I am in here"
  @address.errors.add(:base, "We're sorry, you cant update your address")
  @address.errors.add(:country, "We're sorry, you cant update your address")
end

if @address.update_attributes(params[:address])
  flash[:notice] = 'Information was successfully updated.'
```

But I assumed that if you added an error to the base of an object it would halt but nothing is stopping the update and the flash notice always appears...How do i stop this and add a flash error instead

Comment: Why don't you add this test as a model validation? When saving(true) a record, the errors got reset. It then runs the model validations and only if as least one of the validators added an error, the saving process will be aborted.

Comment: because i dont have access to the current_cart in the model....its defined in application controller...which is not listed in my question but is in the if condition

Comment: If there is no case of addresses outside the USA, you could add the condition in the Address model and not in the CurrentCart model.

Answer (score 5):

Randomly adding an error via `@address.errors.add()` will not cause the record to be invalid. That's why your call to `update_attributes` is still occurring (and not throwing a validation error). As far as I know, to function properly, **`errors.add()` needs to happen inside the rails validation mechanism**. Otherwise, you'll get some strange behavior.

For example, check this out in `rails console`

```
# assume a valid record
@address = Address.first
@address.valid?  # => true
@address.errors.add(:random_error, "random error")
@address.errors  # => {:random_error => ["random error"]}
@address.valid?  # => true
@address.errors  # => [] - call to valid? caused added error to disappear
```

You'd expect the call to `valid?` after adding an error to be `false` but it's not. And it also ends up clearing out the error you just added.

You said you can't move this to the model but that's really the right place for this. You can see more about active record [validations here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html). Notice that all the examples have the validation happening in the models.